# Unity 2D lighting now showing up

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get a light into my game but it doesn't show up in the gameview, only Halo when toggled on shows something:
[image: My problem]

What do i have wrong in this? It is a point light.

While not running
[image: While notrunning]

While running
[image: While Running]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem,
I got rid of all of the normal lights and downloaded the LightWeight RP from the package manager, then I created a 2D light, which is better for 2D, I also followed the tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nkgGyO9VG54

:)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `"Render Mode"` to `important` it should work

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work :/

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the full window?

Comment: I edited the question and put screen shot of when running and when not running

Comment: If you are using URP, which URP version do you use?

Comment: Another solution that you can try is to have the light applied to all layers and modify the sorting layers of the sprites, set them to Sprite-Lit-Default

Comment: I figured it out, i will post an answer

Answer (score 0):

The light works properly. You need an object. Just make sure the light distance from the object, range, and light intensity are sufficient.

[image]

No Effect will be seen without the object.

[image]

Comment: I  can't see the images for some reason :( I have an object called EARTH and then the light  is a child of that, the range is set at 50, the intensity is at 19, but it still won't show anything

Comment: Are the model files healthy? Try them in other software like Blender. Check the cameras if the models are healthy. May have more than one camera per screen. If this problem does not exist, it must be related to the materials.

Comment: Ok so some reason the tag is 3D but when i change it to 2D that doesn't matter, are you thinking 3D or 2D